# React Router Dom, render a component only for some routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a React application with React Router Dom `v6` and trying to render the `Nav` component when the path does NOT match the root `"/"`, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. This is my code:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, matchPath } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from "./components/Nav/Nav";
import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import Contributors from "./components/Contributors/Contributors";

const App = () => {
    const match = matchPath({ path: "/", end: true }, "/");
    return (
        <Router>
            {!match ? <Nav /> : null}
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/contributors" element={<Contributors />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Quick Solution:

You could simply do like below, adding the `Nav` where you want. I'm not sure if you can know the path in `App`, since it's not wrapped inside the `Router`.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, matchPath } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from "./components/Nav/Nav";
import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import Contributors from "./components/Contributors/Contributors";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/contributors" element={<><Nav /><Contributors /></>} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

## Improvement:

And if you want to take it further, instead of doing like above, you could set up a `Layout` component, like this:

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from "../Nav/Nav";

const Layout () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

And render the routes where you want the `Nav` through the `Layout`:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, matchPath } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import Contributors from "./components/Contributors/Contributors";
import Layout from "./components/Layout/Layout";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
                <Route element={<Layout />}>
                   <Route path="/contributors" element={<Contributors />} />
                </Route>
                
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```